# Are these types of blow-ups affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, blowup

When reading Stacks Project I encountered an argument that shows some blow-up is affine. It seems that the situation can be generalised, but I am not very sure if I am missing something, so I would like to know if the following statement is true.

> **Claim:**
>
> Let $S$ be a scheme. If $\forall s\in S$, $\mathscr O_{S,s}$ is Noetherian of dimension $\le1$ (e.g. $S=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ with $R$ Noetherian of dimension $1$) and $\mathcal I$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf of $\mathscr O_S$-ideals of finite type, then the blow-up of $S$ at $\mathcal I$ is affine (as a morphism).

**Attempted proof:**

Consider the blow-up $b:X\to S$ of $S$ at $\mathcal I$. By [Stacks project Lemma 30.32.13](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02NS), $b$ is projective, and hence proper. By [stacks project Lemma 30.32.10](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BFM) and [stacks project Lemma 32.17.2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AB7), $b$ is affine around a neighborhood of any point $s$ of $S$ such that $\mathscr O_{S,s}$ is Noetherian of dimension $\le1$. By our assumptions on $S$, $b$ is affine. $\square$

---

Any thoughts or references are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear to me that all the hypotheses of Lemma 32.17.2 are satisfied automatically, perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: @user45878 We only need one condition to hold. And by Lemma 30.32.10, the generic points of $X$ are in bijection with generic points of $S\setminus Z$, where $Z$ is the closed subscheme corresponding to $\mathcal I$. Since the blow-up is an isomorphism off the center, condition $(1)$ of the lemma 32.17.2 holds. Perhaps I missed something. By the way, I encounter this argument in [Stacks Project Lemma 41.4.2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02Q7).